# How do I convert a tuple stored as a string back to a tuple back into a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, text-files

If I store the tuple `(1, 2, 3)` in a txt file as a string, how could I extract it from the txt file and convert it back to the original tuple?

Comment: saving and loading JSON to files may be the way to go

Comment: **@Milan**, I've updated my answer with again with images. Now I've tested it & it perfectly works. Thanks to **@Zev** who realized me my mistake that I had done by using **json** module.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could use

```
s="(1, 2, 3)"
tuple(int(x) for x in s.strip('()').split(','))
```

Remove the '(' and ')' and then use `tuple()`.

Thanks to [@bla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3044673/bla) for pointing out that `s.strip('()')` can be used instead of `s.replace('(').replace(')')`.

Comment: @Zev You're right. I did a complete re-write. Will it work?

Comment: Yup, looks almost exactly the same as what I came up with. I didn't see that you reposted but I think you got it in there first, so no point of having two of the same answers. I'll remove mine. You just have a quote out of place on that first line.

Comment: I think you can do `s.strip('()')` instead of `s.replace('(', '').replace(')', '')`

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose your tuple is in `MyTuple.txt` then you can try below code written in `ReadTuple.py` to read tuple from a file.

» ReadTuple.py

```
# Open file in read mode
with open('MyTuple.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    content = f.read()
    t = eval(content);

# print tuple t read from file
print(t);

# print type of t
print(type(t));
```

» MyTuple.txt
[image]

Finally, if you will run above code using `python ReadTuple.py` then you will be able to see the read tuple and its type on your screen.

» Output

```
(1, 2, 3)
<class 'tuple'>
```

Comment: Ah yes, the old Python semicolon. Did you test this? A tuple as OP wrote it by iteself isn't valid json.

Comment: **@Zev**, I have updated my answer with 3 images. Now I've tested my code. Now it perfectly works. Please check and let me know.

Comment: Looks better. Not sure why you went with images over code snippets.

Comment: No, I'd just added to make it more clear. Any way everyone is smart in this world. I removed 2 images. I just only kept 1 image. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your file only contains the tuple, you could simply use `eval`.

```
In [1]: with open('tuple.txt') as f:
   ...:     t = eval(f.read())
   ...:     

In [2]: t
Out[2]: (1, 2, 3)
```

Note that `eval` should *not* be used with untrusted input! That means don't use `eval` on some random data that a user can enter or that your program has downloaded from the internet.

Creating `tuple.txt` is not very hard, assuming `t` references the tuple:

```
In [4]: with open('tuple.txt', 'w') as f:
   ...:     f.write(str(t))
   ...:
```

---

*In general* though, I would advise you to use the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module *whenever possible*. It is a pretty general data format that is also easy for people to read. The latter is a good thing for generating test data and catching bugs.

If you have tabular data, then [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) could be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # read it from a file
    with open("filename.txt", "r") as myfile:
        # loop through your text file line by line (if you have multiple of these)
        lines = []
        while True:
            # read a line from text
            line = myfile.readline()
            # add the line to a list
            lines.append(line)
            # if there are no more lines to read, step out of loop
            if not line:
                break
    # create a list of tuples
    list_of_tup = []
    for line in lines:
        # remove next line tag "\n"
        line = line[:-1]
        # use eval() to evaluate a string
        list_of_tup.append(eval(line))
```